# How do I post to a Swagger API?

Tags: php, wordpress, swagger, openapi

I'm using this Swagger based api at https://mybabysfamily-dev.azurewebsites.net/swagger/index.html and having problems with the POST endpoint in particular.

Not having any problems at all with the GET methods, but the POST is a bear. In my case I'm using WordPress's wp_remote_post as follows:

```
$body = array(
    'advisorID' => '{redacted}',
    'vanityID'  => '{redacted}',
    'firstName' => 'Debug',
    'lastName'  => 'Test',
    'email'     => 'debug@email.com',
    'phone'     => '1235551212',
    'zipCode'   => '123456',
    'subject'   => 'Debug test of connect form',
    'message'   => 'Debug This is a test of API submitted connect form'
);

$post_this = array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'cookies' => array(),
    'body'  => json_encode( $body )
);


$test = wp_remote_post( 'https://mybabysfamily-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/advisor/{redacted}/family/{redacted}/connect', $post_this );
```

And it fails with 'Invalid Request'.  Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: you're sending the advisorID and vanityID twice. Once in the URL and then in the body. It doesn't seem right. Is there sandbox or demo credentials for this API?

Comment: Tried without sending it in the body and it still failed.  That link is the only sandbox I have and I can't share what you'd need to get it working due to privacy concerns.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working fine on my end. It does return `Family not found` but that's because it uses fake credentials. Anyway the request is going trough.

[Live Demo](http://deepcorelabs.com/projects/so/swagger_api_test/)

I tested with the following code:

```
$test = wp_remote_post( 'https://mybabysfamily-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/advisor/12345678-4444-1234-1234-123456789012/family/test/connect', $post_this);

print_r($test);
```